# "Pattern match is redundant" when using input list argument inside list comprehension

Tags: list, function, haskell, list-comprehension

This is my code:

```
example = [1,-4,7,12]

positiveSum :: [Int] -> Int
positiveSum (x) = 0
positiveSum (x:xs) = result
  where 
    result = sum [y+y | y <- xs, y > 0]

main = do
  print (positiveSum example)
```

When I run it I get:

```
Main.hs:5:1: warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
    Pattern match is redundant
    In an equation for `positiveSum': positiveSum (x : xs) = ...
  |
5 | positiveSum (x:xs) = result
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I can't use 'xs' inside the list comprehension and I don't understand why. It's a reference, and I should be able to use it. Why is it redundant?

Edit:

The answer solved the problem, I was matching anything with the first (x). Also, I confused myself and was applying sum twice. This is the right code:

```
positiveSum :: [Int] -> Int
positiveSum [] = 0
positiveSum xs = result
  where 
    result = sum [x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```

Comment: The `positiveSum [] = 0` clause is not necessary: `sum []` is `0`, so `positiveSum xs = sum [x | x <- xs, x > 0]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to think `positiveSum (x) = 0` will only match the case of an empty list, but that will in fact match anything, which makes the next line redundant since it will never get tried. You meant to write `positiveSum [] = 0` there. Also, note that your second case, even though it will now run, will throw away the head of the list, which you probably didn't mean to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Learning Haskell is a true challenge coming from an imperative background.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern matches go top to bottom, so every call to `positiveSum` returns `0`. Since the pattern for the first rule is `positiveSum (x) = 0`, which matches *everything*, since every value can be bound to `x`. By making that rule the last one, you can avoid this issue:

```hs
positiveSum :: [Int] -> Int
positiveSum (x:xs) = result
  where 
    result = sum [y+y | y <- xs, y > 0]
positiveSum (x) = 0
```

With this code, we only fall back to the `0` case if there isn't a tail for the argument, causing the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to make a distinction between an empty list and a non-empty list: you can calculate the sum of the filtered list with:

```
positiveSum :: [Int] -> Int
positiveSum xs = sum [y | y <- xs, y > 0]
```

Here `xs` pattern matches thus with *all* possible lists: empty or not empty. `y` will enumerate over all items of `xs`, and if `y > 0`, we yield that value. We then calculate the sum of that list. For an empty list `sum` will return `0`, so regardless if `xs` is empty or not, and that there are elements that satisfy the `y > 0` predicate, it will return a value.

Another option is to work with [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) and thus determine the sum with:

```
positiveSum :: [Int] -> Int
positiveSum = sum . filter (0 <)
```